# Write to a stream_parser using a flat_buffer

Tags: c++, json, boost, websocket

I am trying to build a program that listens to websockets in C++, those websocktes come as Json files and I want to parse the websocket message with boost::json::stream_parser

My code looks something like the following:

```
beast::websocket::stream<ssl::stream<tcp::socket>> ws;

boost::beast::flat_buffer buffer;

boost::json::stream_parser parser;

ws.read(buffer);

parser.write(buffer, buffer.size());

assert(parser.done());

boost::json::value jsn = parser.release();
```

Pretending that the websocket client works (because it does, I can write the message to terminal with `boost::make_printable(buffer.data)`), what is the right parameter for my parser in order to successfully read from my buffer.
Right now I am getting this message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>'
 what():  extra data [boost.json:2 at /usr/include/boost_1_79_0/boost/json/impl/stream_parser.ipp:108 in function 'write']
```

Comment: Could you post a small example of the JSON content that produces this error.

Comment: I wonder if you have read the section `Extra Data` in the documentation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__parser.html)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot to call [finish()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_79_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/ref/boost__json__stream_parser/finish.html).

I'm currently working on custom `json_body` for which you may be able to look a t a (very rough!) draft here: https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/6403e0acd9c07a9e7f53a2bf1fb43fbb27cacf06/example/json-body/http_client_json_body.cpp

Specifically it should not be supplying a precalculated size - instead opting to be HTTP/1.1 only by using chunked encoding.